# Can I connect a Thunderbolt Display and a MacBook Retina 12" using usb-c to thunderbolt 2 adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a Thunderbolt Display and am looking at buying a MacBook Retina. Is it possible to connect it to my Thunderbolt Display using the newly presented [usb-c to thunderbolt 2 adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use your MacBook 12" with a Thunderbolt Display.

Per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), you need a Mac with a Thunderbolt connection in order to drive this display and the MacBook just doesn't have that capability

[image]

The Thunderbolt Display is more of a Thunderbolt hub with a display attached rather than a mini Display Port display with Thunderbolt compatability.

The port on the MacBook 12" (Early 2015) is USB C 3.1 only and no adapter will convert USB to TB.

Comment: they just released this one http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter are you saying it won't work with a thunderbolt display?

Comment: That won't work.  That's for the new MBP with USB-C connectors on the TB  ports.

Comment: I see, so even though they have the same connectors they don't have the same capabilities... Thanks a lot, you saved me from a nightmare!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this does not work. I'm trying to connect a MacBook 12" Early 2016 model to an iMac in target disc mode using the usb-c to thunderbolt 2 adapter and the MacBook reports that no Thunderbolt hardware is found.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did you figure out a way to convert the display's charger cable with adapter(s) to usb-c?