# Connecting a Thunderbolt MacBook to a USB-C-based display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

In other words, how to connect MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) to Apple Studio display? What cables/adapters to use?

Comment: Could this be helpful? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259268/61388

Answer (score 1):

The latest Apple Studio Display (2022) uses a Thunderbolt 3 connection for video. You will need [this adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) to connect to the monitor and [this cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD862LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-05-m) to connect with the Thunderbolt 2 port on your MBP.

Don't skimp on these two accessories. If you can find similar Belkin or Anker items, those are acceptable substitutes. Years of testing adapters and cables of all sorts for my job has lead to these two manufacturers (other than Apple-branded items) as having the best build quality and proper specs. (Apple-recommended items also make the grade, or Apple wouldn't make them available in their store.)

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I have no financial interest or ties with Belkin, Anker  or Apple.</sub>

Comment: But I guess that this adapter is not compatible with MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). Is it?

Comment: Plug the TBolt-3 adapter end into the Display, connect one end of the TBolt-2 cable to the TBolt-2 adapter jack and the other end into your MBP TBolt-2 jack.

Comment: According to the adapter specifications (you mentioned above) that it's not compatible with MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). Do you think that this way will work with me though?

Comment: From the description: _As a bidirectional adapter, it can also connect new Thunderbolt 3 devices to a Mac with a Thunderbolt or Thunderbolt 2 port and macOS Sierra or later._ You don't mention which macOS version is running on your MBP. If you are running version of macOS earlier than Sierra, then there's that to consider.

Comment: And do you think that the camera and speakers of the display will work with me too?

Comment: Impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

With Apple's TB3 adapter and TB2 cable, Studio display could identify and re-arrange/change resolution by my MacBook Air early 2014(Catalina) and it works with keyboard connected to it. But the display does NOT show anything and the brightness seem not configurable. Not sure if it works in future, but at least the display doesn't work for now.